django IntegrityError: Check constraint failed: new__blog_blogpage
I'm trying to build a blog using Django(wagtail cms) and have this error now that I'm not quite sure I understand. I'm assuming it has to do with my blog model. I've been googling for a day and half with no success. Many times the results are for NOT NULL constraint or ForeignKey error, but obviously my error is something different...
I'm going to post my entire blog model because of the error text: new__blog_blogpage
I just kept building off the getting started tutorial from wagtail docs and much of their demo project on github. I'm just not using all that code, mainly just the blog stuff...
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField

from wagtail.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel, MultipleChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

from base.blocks import BaseStreamBlock

# add this:
from wagtail.search import index

# keep the definition of BlogIndexPage model, and add the BlogPage model:

class BlogPersonRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(
        "BlogPage", related_name="blog_person_relationship", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        "base.Person", related_name="person_blog_relationship", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    panels = [FieldPanel("person")]


class BlogPage(Page):
    introduction = models.TextField(help_text="Text to describe the page.", blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
        help_text="Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.",
    )
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True, use_json_field=True
    )
    subtitle = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    # tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True) CURRENTLY NOT USING TAGS
    date_published = models.DateField("Date article published", blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("subtitle"),
        FieldPanel("introduction"),
        FieldPanel("image"),
        FieldPanel("body"),
        FieldPanel("date_published"),
        MultipleChooserPanel(
            "blog_person_relationship",
            chooser_field_name="person",
            heading="Authors",
            label="Author",
            panels=None,
            min_num=1,
        ),
        # FieldPanel("tags"),
    ]

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
            index.SearchField("body"),
    ]

    def authors(self):
        # only return authors that are not in draft
        return [
            n.person
            for n in self.blog_person_relationship.filter(
                person__live=True
            ).select_related("person")
        ]

    # Specifies parent to BlogPage as being BlogIndexPages
    parent_page_types = ["BlogIndexPage"]

    # Specifies what content types can exist as children of BlogPage
    # Empty list means that no child content types are allowed
    subpage_types = []


class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    # intro = RichTextField(blank=True) # wagtail docs getting started tutorial
    introduction = models.TextField(help_text="Text to describe the page.", blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
        help_text="Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.",
    )
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("introduction"),
        FieldPanel("image"),
    ]

    # add the get_context method:
    def get_context(self, request):
        # update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        # blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')
        # context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(request)
        context["posts"] = (
            BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live().order_by("-date_published")
        )        
        return context
    
    def serve_preview(self, request, mode_name):
        # needed for previews to work
        return self.serve(request)
    
    # returns the child BlogPage objects for this BlogPageIndex
    # if a tag is used then it will filter the posts by tag
    def get_posts(self, tag=None):
        posts = BlogPage.objects.live().descendant_of(self)
        # if tag:
            # posts = posts.filter(tags=tag)
        return posts

Edit 1(screenshot of error from the browser)
This is the error I get when I try to go to the blog via the admin area:
OperationalError at /admin/pages/4/
no such column: blog_blogindexpage.introduction
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/4/
Django Version: 4.2.11
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: blog_blogindexpage.introduction
Exception Location: /home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during:  wagtail.admin.views.pages.listing.IndexView
Python Executable:  /home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/david/projects/someproject/about/about',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 16 Apr 2024 18:18:24 +0000

Edit 2
I was running the makemigrations and migrate commands when I first encountered this error. This is what my terminal prints out
Running migrations:
  Applying blog.0006_remove_blogindexpage_intro_remove_blogpage_authors_and_more...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: new__blog_blogpage

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 356, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 132, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 235, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 175, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 831, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 463, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_fields=[(old_field, new_field)])
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 336, in _remake_table
    self.execute(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 201, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/david/projects/someproject/about/venv-about/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: new__blog_blogpage


Could you please show the error message and tell us what you are doing when you see it? I can't tell from your description if the issue is with the Image or with one of the relationships created by BlogPersonRelationship

@cnk - I posted a screenshot of the error I get when I try to go to the blog in the admin area. I can post something from the terminal if you want but much of it is just django core, not my code. I actually first came across this error when running python3 manage.py migrate command from the terminal. Let me know if you need more...

@cnk - I added edit 2, printout from my terminal after running makemigrations and migrate commands, that is what I was doing when I first encountered this error.

Sorry. Wish I could help but those error messages aren't giving me any clues.

@cnk - np. That is why I posted bcuz I had no clue... thankfully I'm not too far into the project that I think I'll just start fresh....
